# multiprocessing threadpool not terminating as expected

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm running Python 3.4 on Windows 7.

I'm trying to understand more about multiprocessing, and doing so by trying to write a function that performs a clean little timeout on another function call.  But I've run into a problem I can't figure out.

According to the Python docs on Multiprocessing:

> Terminate() "Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work."

However, when I test this, `pool.terminate()` seems to wait for the worker processes to finish instead of killing them!

So when I run this code:

```
import multiprocessing.pool
from time import sleep

def timeout(seconds, function, *args, **kwargs):

    pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes = 1)
    result = pool.apply_async(function, args, kwargs)

    try: result.get(seconds)
    except multiprocessing.context.TimeoutError:
        print("Process timed out")
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()
        print("Pool terminated")
    finally:
        pool.close()

def worker():
    for n in range(5):
        sleep(1)
        print(n+1)
    print("Process succeeded")

timeout(2.5, worker)
```

I expect the result to be this:

```
1
2
Process timed out
Pool terminated
```

But instead I get this:

```
1
2
Process timed out
3
4
5
Process succeeded
Pool terminated
```

I know that `result.get` raised the `TimeoutError` because the message "Process timed out" printed successfully.  And I know that `pool.terminate()` was called for the same reason, it just didn't seem to do anything!

I feel like there is something here that I'm just not understanding. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a Windows issue - with Linux it's almost certainly sending a signal, which is not available on Windows 7 AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but the issue appears to be caused by the `pool.join()` call, which you don't really need anyway, since the worker processes were supposedly terminated by the preceding `terminate()` call.

```
import multiprocessing.pool
from time import sleep

def timeout(seconds, function, *args, **kwargs):
    pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=1)
    result = pool.apply_async(function, args, kwargs)
    try:
        result.get(timeout=seconds)
    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
        print("Process timed out")
    pool.terminate()
#    pool.join()  # Don't need this, all worker threads have been stopped.
    print("Pool terminated")

def worker():
    for n in range(5):
        sleep(1)
        print(n+1)
    print("Process succeeded")

timeout(2.5, worker)
```

Output:

```
1
2
Process timed out
Pool terminated
```

Regardless, note that since version 3.3, `Pool` objects support the context management protocol, which means `Pool.terminate()` will be called automatically when it's used — so the function could have been more succinctly written like this:

```
def timeout(seconds, function, *args, **kwargs):
    with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=1) as pool:
        result = pool.apply_async(function, args, kwargs)
        try:
            result.get(timeout=seconds)
        except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
            print("Process timed out")
    print("Pool terminated")
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a really helpful answer.  I was following some advice I found elsewhere (can't find it now) that you should always follow a terminate() with a join(), but I guess that's bunk.  I did notice that while this works when running the python script normally, it doesn't work when running it in IDLE.  Do you have any ideas how to fix that?  Or is that too much to ask for?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, have no real idea why it wouldn't also work in IDLE (especially since I don't use it myself). Exactly how does it not work?

Comment: As an experiment, try making the `timeout(2.5, worker)` conditional by preceding it with an `if __name__ == '__main__':` (or whatever the IDLE equivalent of that would be).